# Python package path broken

Tags: python, path, package

I'm working on two python packages, they have the same config and the same files structure (i'm following the python default structure defined here : https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/ ).

One is working fine and is published in PyPI.
The second got an issue with it's path.

Normally, in the package that works fine i say:

```
from mypackage.mymodule import MyClass
```

But in the second package i just can't. I have to specify the "src" folder, like that :

```
from src.mypackage.mymodule import MyClass
```

I don't understand because the difference between them is really thin.
Even PyCharm saw the difference, in the good package the "src" folder is in blue, in the other the "src" is in gray, like a normal folder.

Someone got an idea ?
Thx in advance

The problematic package :
https://github.com/Morgiver/morpyneural

The package that work fine :
https://github.com/Morgiver/morpyengine

EDIT: Ok the problem is solved, but i cannot findout why.
So if someone know what happened, it will be kind to share, thx !

Comment: Have you tried relative paths instead of absolute paths?

Comment: Nope, haven't try it.
But, i'm back from work, i have pull the project on my personnal computer and now this is working ...

I'm a bit confused :-/